# Asymptotic Problem Complexity = Infimum of Asymptotic Algorithm Complexities?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, order-theory, computational-complexity, computability

When talking about the complexity of algorithms and problems, the complexity of a problem is the infimum of the complexities of the algorithms that solve the problem.

My question is:

> Is the asymptotic complexity of the problem always the infimum of the
>   asymptotic complexities of the algorithms?

This is certainly not the case if we take infima of arbitrary functions, not only of those corresponding to algorithms solving a specific problem. For example, take

\begin{equation}
f_i(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & n<i\text{,}\\ n & \text{else.}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

We have
\begin{equation}
\Theta(\inf_i f_i) = \Theta(1)\text{,}
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
\inf_i \Theta(f_i) = \inf_i\Theta(n)=\Theta(n)\text{.}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem that you've found in the abstract case can show up for actual problems.

Pick your favorite decision problem with really really bad asymptotic complexity: say, $\Theta(2^{2^n})$.

We're going to define a sequence of algorithms for this problem. The $k^{\text{th}}$ algorithm in this sequence will treat $k$-bit inputs as a special case.

Whatever the decision problem is, deciding it for all $k$-bit inputs is equivalent to computing some function $f:\{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$. By a result of Shannon, there is a circuit of size $O(2^k/k)$ computing $f$; the algorithm will handle all $k$-bit inputs by just evaluating this circuit. This takes polynomial time in the size of the circuit, so we can bound the time by $C^k$ for some constant $C$ (the same constant $C$ works for all $k$). For all other input sizes, the algorithm will just default to whatever the $\Theta(2^{2^n})$ approach is.

All of these algorithms have asymptotic complexity $\Theta(2^{2^n})$. But the actual functions representing these complexities look like
$$
   f_i(n) = \begin{cases}C^n & n = k, \\ 2^{2^n} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
and so taking their pointwise infimum gives us a function which is $\Theta(C^n)$.

---

This is actually a really important feature of complexity theory: we need to distinguish the circuit complexity of a problem (the size of a circuit needed to solve it on $n$ bits, as a function of $n$) from the uniform circuit complexity (the size of a circuit needed, if there must be a Turing machine that outputs the $n^{\text{th}}$ circuit in $\operatorname{poly}(n)$ time). The construction above is exploiting the non-uniformity of the circuits Shannon's theorem gives us.

P.S. I guess we could replace the use of Shannon's theorem in this argument by a lookup table, but then we wouldn't get the nice connection to circuit complexity.

Comment: Very nice, I already thought about finding problems where I could construct special algorithms which are faster for some fixed $n$, but I didn't realize that this would be much easier if the asymptotic complexity is so bad.

Comment: Originally, I came up with the question because I tried to prove that the infimum of the asymptotic complexities always exists. So now that this line of reasoning didn't work, I wonder, does this infimum always exist?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to define it carefully. If an algorithm is $\Theta(n)$, it is also $\Theta(\frac12n)$, $\Theta(\frac13n)$, and so on, and taking the infimum of these functions naively gives us the nonsense result $\Theta(0)$.

Comment: My idea was the following: We can view the $\Theta$s as equivalence classes of functions with the same asymptotic behavior. There is a partial order on this set of all $\Theta$s defined by $\Theta(f)\leq\Theta(g)$ iff $f\in\mathcal{O}(g)$. Now we can apply the notion of an infimum of a subset of a partially ordered set. Of course, such an infimum might not always exist, leading to my question.